# Problem when both sendmail and mimedefang runs as unpriviledged user

Tags: permissions, sendmail

I'm trying to implement an anti-spam  solution and according to advices I get here from answers to my other questions, I have decided to go for sendmail+mimedefang+spamassassin.

But currently I'm stuck with quite simple permission problem:

1. By default, MIMEdefang is run as "defang" user, so it creates it's socket with following permissions:

   srwxr-x--- 1 defang defang 0 Mar  3 16:42 /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.sock
2. If sendmail is run as root, there is no problem, but if it is run as unprivileged user, then it complain about lack of permissions for mimedefang socket:

   NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 1870: Xmimedefang: local socket name /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.sock unsafe: Permission denied

I have already tried following solutions for this problem:

1. run sendmail as root. Works ok, but is rather unacceptable, as I want to  avoid running my daemons as root
2. run sendmail as defang or run mimedefang as the same user as sendmail. Seems ok, but also want to avoid this, as there are too many configurations files, directories, etc., which would require changing permissions and/or ownership, so whole process became much error prone.
3. Simply change permission of socket file, but it is recreated every time mimedefang starts. I could modify accordingly appropriate scripts in /etc/init.d but again wan't to avoid this because my changes may be loosed with future updates of  those packages.

Could you suggest any other solution? Are there available any options  in sendmail or mimedefang, which are related with permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendmail runs as root and forks whenever needed processes to run as another user (smmsp, smmta, etc). So yes, run it as root and make sure you are running the latest version. If you want to run sendmail as non-root, make that user part of the defang group. Notice that the defang group also has read rights on the socket.

EDIT: (after reading the comments bellow) To make the socket group read-write [you have to use umask](https://www.milter.org/developers/api/smfi_setconn) appropriately before starting the milter (See the Notes section in the link provided).

Comment: Thank, you for your answer, but this dosn't solve problem, as adding sendmail to defang group gives sendmail only read permissions while it require also write permissions. I have workarounded this problem using inet socket (f.e. inet:2222@127.0.0.1) instead of unix one, but I'm wonder whether there could be any negative consequences of this.

Comment: Duh! I should have read my comment more closely before submitting it! Of course it needs write access too! How else are they supposed to exchange information? Using the network socket is not a problem. It is there as a means to have the milter running on a machine different from the mail servers querrying it.

Comment: BTW, read https://www.milter.org/developers/api/smfi_setconn to see how to create the socket 0660 using umask when starting the milter.

Comment: @adamo Thanks! Milter is down, but it was archived: http://web.archive.org/web/20100713212558/https://www.milter.org/developers/api/smfi_setconn

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't need to set umask for creating socket. I just need to run opendkim with the same user and group as sendmail (`RunAsUid`, `RunAsGid`) and have directory used for socket with `600` permission (`S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR`).

You can check it in sendmail sources [1]:

- sendmail/milter.c

```
errno = safefile(colon, RunAsUid, RunAsGid, RunAsUserName, sff,
         S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR, NULL);
...
else if (errno != 0)
{
    /* if not safe, don't create */
    save_errno = errno;
    if (tTd(64, 5))
        sm_dprintf("X%s: local socket name %s unsafe\n",
            m->mf_name, colon);
```

- libsmutil/safefile.c

```
/*
**  SAFEFILE -- return 0 if a file exists and is safe for a user.
**
**  Parameters:
**      fn -- filename to check.
**      uid -- user id to compare against.
**      gid -- group id to compare against.
**      user -- user name to compare against (used for group
**          sets).
**      flags -- modifiers:
**          SFF_MUSTOWN -- "uid" must own this file.
**          SFF_NOSLINK -- file cannot be a symbolic link.
**      mode -- mode bits that must match.
**      st -- if set, points to a stat structure that will
**          get the stat info for the file.
**
**  Returns:
**      0 if fn exists, is owned by uid, and matches mode.
**      An errno otherwise.  The actual errno is cleared.
**
**  Side Effects:
**      none.
*/

int
safefile(fn, uid, gid, user, flags, mode, st)
```

[1]: ftp://ftp.sendmail.org/pub/sendmail/sendmail.8.15.2.tar.gz